# How to obtain the proxy resolver configuration of a Virtualbox VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns, nat

Virtualbox provides two configuration flags to modify the DNS behavior of the NAT engine for a virtual machine:

- [`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnsproxy1 on`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns)
- [`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat_host_resolver_proxy)

However, I don't know how to obtain the state of those flags given an existing VM (e.g. a virtual machine called `"VM name"` like in the example above). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there is a way, via the command line, the read the current state of those settings (you could use the COM API or parse the XML file where the settings are stored).  Why do you need to get the setting?

Comment: To identify what VMs are affected by this bug https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15074 . Looking into the settings file would be perfectly fine, hadn't thought about that, thanks! Want to add an answer? I could do it myself but the idea came from you.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, as **heavyd** suggested, you can check current settings this way:

1. open your VM's folder
2. look for the file with `.vbox` extension, open it with any text editor
3. look for the strings `use-proxy="true"` and `use-host-resolver="true"` to check current status of `natdnsproxy1` and `natdnshostresolver1` parameters. If one of these parameters (or both) is not present in the file, this means the parameter is set to `off` state.