# How to display/show/output settings of VBoxManage modifyvm including those of natdnshostresolver?

Tags: virtualbox

Relevant background:

1. Subset question [How to obtain the proxy resolver configuration of a Virtualbox VM](https://superuser.com/questions/1031174/how-to-obtain-the-proxy-resolver-configuration-of-a-virtualbox-vm) .
2. [modifyvm official docs](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm) don't seem to answer this (a notable doc bug); for those who don't know natdnshostresolver, it does document that (for just setting, not displaying) in [NAT Network Settings](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm4054).
3. showvminfo, officially documented at http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-showvminfo ,  (my only use) doesn't display natdnshostresolver other than just say a ‘NAT’ is present.
4. Even ugly mostly-afterthought bash has ways to display all its flags set by its ‘set’ command, so ‘VirtualBox, what ya thinking making commands to set settings which you don't readily display?? You even have [‘Display settings’](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display) but here you readily won't *display settings* ;-)’
5. What now motivates me to ask: I was recommended to use `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on` from https://superuser.com/a/722670/327105 , and (after turning off the VM) I able to get that to setting to execute without error but afterwards there was no change so fix from it, so to diagnose that I want to query the setting to see if the setting stuck and to query a default machine's setting to see what it was before, but can't find how to do that, so ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no VBoxManage command line that I could find. But here is a manual way to confirm:

```
grep 'use-host-resolver="true"' ~/'VirtualBox VMs/VM name/VM name.vbox'
# replace "VM name" with the actual path to the .vbox file
```

By default, you will get no result. But after executing 
`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natdnshostresolver1 on`, you should get:

```
<DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="true"/>
```